# Can we allow certain degree of customized home page in stackoverflow

Tags: feature-request, login, information-display

I thinks stackoverflow must allow some degree of customization for user - the page he needs to see after login.

There is a definite use case for this - like I want all questions regarding C++ topic to be seen immediately after login, another user XYZ wants to see all "Unanswered questions in C++" after login.

I think it is worth giving it a try.

Comment: Does your browser not allow bookmarks?

Comment: Yes It does, but what If I login from multiple machine. An in built customization is more preferable I guess.

Comment: A real developer loves his computer and never switches to another one. They don't even bother leaving it.